# Rectangle before cursor in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this strange rectangle in Eclipse and haven't seen this before. It doesn't show up in the code anywhere else.

[image]

How can I fix this from showing up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally such a "rectangle cursor" only occurs when you start a refactoring or use templates, such that Eclipse expects you to input a new name for an identifier or other symbol. If that is the case, this cursor vanishes by simply hitting <kbd>Escape</kbd>.